# discordia message.content is a nil value

Tags: lua, discord

### im making a bot in lua using discordia but the print(message.content) returns a nil value or blank space

```
`local discordia = require('discordia')
local client = discordia.Client()
client:on('ready', function()
    print('Logged in as '.. client.user.username)
end)

client:on('messageCreate', function(message)
    local Content = message.content
    local author = message.author
    print(Content)
    if Content:lower() == '!ping' then
        message:reply('Pong!')
    end
end)

client:run('Bot '..TOKEN)`
```

- 

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn on message content intent in the discord developer portal in the Bot tab? That's probably causing the empty strings.[image]